# IPhone Ad-hoc distribution sync error

Tags: iphone, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I am working on an iPhone application for a customer. After the development will be finished the application will be on the Apple Store, but meanwhile during its development, on a regular basis the customer wants to see and install the application on his own phone to check the current status of the development.
-I went to the provisioning portal registered my customer's device udid and added to my application's provisioning profile.
-I downloaded the provisioning profile and installed it.
-I then built the ipa and sent it to my customer.

SHouldn't this be enough?

The customer is experimenting a sync error. He can import the ipa inside itunes but at the end of the sync he receive this error alert on his iphone.I tested this ipa file on two other iphones  and is working (both registered and one is ios 5.1 and the other 5.0.1)..Where should I check for misconfigurations?

I'm running the latest xcode version 4.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you build with the distribution provision.  I use a new Xcode build configuration for this (called Ad Hoc) and I make sure my archive build uses this new build configuration.  The customer will need a copy of this distribution provision (which he double clicks), and you send him the ipa file.  He drags this into his iTunes library and he is then able to install the app to his device.

Comment: I'm using the development provisioning profile is this wrong?

Comment: Yes - if you go back to your iOS portal, you will see a distribution tab.  Create a profile there and download it.  Then build using this profile.  The easiest way is to create a new scheme configuration (so you have debug, release and adhoc) and make sure you're using the distribution version.  Now set the archive build to use your new adhoc distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the provisioning profile needs to be installed on the device separately. I encountered this problem once with my team member who had Windows.

Just send your customer the profile and ask to install it on the device.

You may need [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/) to install the profile on the device.

Comment: You do need the provisioning profile (distribution version).  You can install it on the Mac by double-clicking it.  It will be automatically added to your keychain and to your device when it needs it.  Possibly with the PC you need a utility.

Comment: In most cases, the profile gets automatically installed on the device along with the app, from iTunes.

Comment: It does, but you need to add it to your machine first so that iTunes can get it.  So you can imagine ftp'ing the profile, double-clicking on the .mobileprovision file and now it's ready for iTunes to install on your device along with the app.